# Auto log multiple users through command line

Tags: windows, batch

Hope everyone doing great.

I wanted to Logoff multiple users from single syntax through command line.

Now, if I have the 10 users on that machine and I wa t to exclude 2 users and Logoff 8 users.

If their is a way to do from command line share your input.

Thanks...

Comment: We're not a script writing service, but here are some pointers. Use `query session` to get a list of active session ID's. Use `logoff x` where x is a session ID. Lastly; remember that a remote logoff will force close all applications, so any unsaved work will be lost.

Comment: ... and some services/applications will reconnect immediately after disconnecting detection (or by user/code activity) - i.e. the account disconnected first may already reconnect before batch finishes.